# How to run Jupyter Notebook on server

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook

I've used Jupyter Notebook before on my local computer as well as Jupyter Hub, but now I'm trying to install it on my Ubuntu server so that I can access it from everywhere, but I can't make it work.

I tried using SSH tunneling, but then I don't get the right permissions, and I don't want to make my share open globaly.

I did it like this on the server:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

On the local machine I used:

```
ssh -f user@server -L 8889:localhost:8889 -N
```

When I create a new Notebook it says:

```
Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.local/share'
```

It does work when I run the Jupyter Notebook as root with `sudo`, but that's not a recommend way to start Jupyter Notebook.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jupyter is fine but you do not have the rights to write in the folder where you want to write in the terminal:

```
chmod 666 /home/user/.local/share
```

or

```
sudo chmod 666 /home/user/.local/share
```

/home/user/.local/share is where you are saving
chmod 666 will grant you right to write and read there. You could select instead of 666 other combinations, dependind if you want to give right to write to read and so on. For further info on that http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command/chmod-permissions-flags-explained-600-0600-700-777-100-etc.
sudo because you may need to have the right to give the rights.

Comment: It looks similar to this case https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2923. Is it actually there the directory?. In the link case it try to create but it couldn't and at the end it has to be created manually and grant writing rights.

Comment: As i say it works when i run jupyter as root. But again thats not recommend.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please try sudo chmod 666 /home/user/.local/share instead of sudo chmod 644 /home/user/.local/share?

Comment: Still the same.. strange.. i dont know what is safer btw. To give all users permission or just run jupyter notebook as sudo, and password protect the jupyter notebook app.

Comment: if you go to the folder (as a normal user and as a root) can you create files?. Maybe is worthy to try sudo chmod 777 /home/user/.local/share, that will allow to execute files too. Best of lucks

Comment: Maybe is better to use another folder. I usually use one in the folder Documet, assuming user "ubuntu"´jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889 --notebook-dir=/home/ubuntu/Documents´, maybe you could do something similar. Best

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer, it is permissions issue: you can try

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/user/.local/share
```

Comment: I believe `chmod 755` should be used for security reasons compared to `chmod 777`.